# Estimation of outer content/measure

Tags: real-analysis

Let be

$ f : B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ , Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitzcontant $ \lambda $.

$ B \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ is bounded

How to proof that the outer content/measure of the image $f(B)$ can be estimated like this :
$ \bar{i} (f(B)) \leq (2  \lambda \root \of n  )^n \bar{i}(B) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may prove it by using cubes. Fix a cube $C=[a_1,b_1]\times...\times[a_n,b_n]$ with $b_i-a_i=r>0$. The diameter of the cube $C$ is less or equal to $r\sqrt n$, for
$$
\|x-y\|=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+...+(x_n-y_n)^2}\leq \sqrt{nr^2} =r\sqrt{n},\ \ \forall x,y\in C.
$$
Then,
$$
\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq \lambda r\sqrt{n},\ \ \forall x,y\in C.
$$
Therefore, the projection of $f(C)$ on each coordinate of $\mathbb R^n$ must be contained in an interval of diameter $\lambda r\sqrt n$, so $f(C)$ is contained in a cube $C'$ with dimensions equal to $\lambda r\sqrt n$ and so, $\overline i(C')=(\lambda r\sqrt n)^n=(\lambda\sqrt n)^n\overline i(C),$ so it follows that
$$
\overline i(f(C))\leq (\lambda\sqrt n)^n\overline i(C).
$$
Now we shall use the fact that the outer measure doesn't change if we define it with respect to coverings by cubes. Then, for any covering $(C_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $B$ by cubes, proceeding as above for each $C_n$, we get a sequence of cubes $(C'_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ which covers $f(B)$ and such that, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $\overline i(C_n')=(\lambda\sqrt n)^n\overline i(C_n)$. Therefore,
$$
\overline i(f(B)) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\overline i(C_n') \leq (\lambda\sqrt n)^n\sum_{n=1}^\infty\overline i(C_n),
$$
and, since it happens for any covering $(C_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $B$, it follows by taking the infimum on these coverings that
$$
\overline i(f(B)) \leq (\lambda\sqrt n)^n\overline i(B).
$$

Comment: sorry for my late reply..but yeah that's great ! would never think of prove it by using cubes ! thanks!